# DockerFile execution is not working from kubernates job

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

we are in process of migrating init-container to kubernates job . so I added init-container image location in containers section of job.yaml. but shell script execution within .dockerfile of init-container is not getting invoked. Could some one help what could be wrong here?

job.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-init-job"
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/inject: disabled
        "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
        "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,pre-delete
        "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Release.Name }}-init-service-account
      containers:
        - name: app-installer
          image: artifactorylocation/test-init-container:1.0.1
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - echo Hello executing k8s init-container
          securityContext:
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

.dockerfile of test-init-container

```
FROM repository/java17-ol8-x64:adddd4c

WORKDIR /

ADD target/test-init-container-ms.jar ./
ADD target/lib ./lib

ADD start.sh /
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD ["sh", "/start.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

start.sh is not been executed by job.

Comment: You are overriding the `CMD` in your Dockerfile by providing a `command` in the pod manifest.

Comment: Remove command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - echo Hello executing k8s init-container, this from manifest and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your job.yml to avoid replacing the entrypoint(CMD):

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-init-job"
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/inject: disabled
        "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
        "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,pre-delete
        "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Release.Name }}-init-service-account
      containers:
        - name: app-installer
          image: artifactorylocation/test-init-container:1.0.1
          securityContext:
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```